# RemoveAt index c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a project I am struggling on how to remove from a list.

The list item that I want to delete is whatever item is at the index that the users selects from a list box.

The project has a class for the list named Pickcuplist and 2 GUI one for the main form and one for the pickup form.  The pickup form is where the delete button will be however the list box with the index that is selected is on the main form.

I found List.RemoveAt however I can't seem to get that to work.

items are added to the list like from the pickups form form like:

```
txtCustName.Text = thePickup.name;
txtCustAddress.Text = thePickup.address;
txtArrival.Text = thePickup.arrival.ToString();
txtDaddress.Text = thePickup.Daddress;
txtDeliveryName.Text = thePickup.Dname;
LblType.Text = thePickup.type;
```

and this is the code for the main form add

```
  /*
            * This method creates a new pickup object, allows the user to
            * enter details and adds it to the List
            *  
            */

        Pickupform.pickup = new Pickups();
        //New Visit- note added to the pickupform object

        Pickupform.ShowDialog();
        //Show the pickupForm. ShowDialog ensures that the form has the exclusive focus until it is closed.

        if (Pickupform.pickup != null)
        //if null then the "cancel" button was pressed
        {
            Pickups newpic = Pickupform.pickup;
            //Get the Pickup object from the form

            thePickup.addPickups(newpic);
            //Add the visit to the list
        }
        updateList();
        //Update the list object to reflect the Pickups in the list
```

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to remove...

Comment: And what exactly does not work about `RemoveAt`?

Comment: Where's the code for removing items?

Comment: @<Chris> that is one of the problems I have no idea where to put the remove thing, I was thrown right into this with no experience so I am kind of guessing

Comment: Somewhere you will need a thePickup.RemoveAt(index) if you wish to remove an item.

Comment: This is what I have `theList.listVisits().RemoveAt(int index);` but its saying index isn't a valid option

Comment: index must be an integer...

Comment: @TAM that line of code (`theList.listVisits().RemoveAt(int index);`) isn't valid C#, and it's not even close enough to valid to know where to begin correcting it.  You might want to brush up on basic C# programming concepts and syntax before proceeding.

Comment: theList.listVisits().RemoveAt(1); could be valid, which is kind-of close enough... But I still agree on the brushing up on basic C# knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link (http://www.dotnetperls.com/removeat)

The crux of it is this bit:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("dot");
list.Add("net");
list.Add("perls");

list.RemoveAt(1); <-- See, you pass in an integer
```

So in your case, you will have an event or something that triggers the remove, at which time you need to find the index of the item you wish to remove and call the method. If you're struggling with this, you should really consider doing some tutorials, this is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the class that represents the `Form` that has the Delete button.

Find the event handler that is attached to the `Click` event of this button.

If you have access to the pickupList from this class, call `RemoveAt` from there.

If you don't have access to it, find a way to pass the list to the other form. For example, if the form with the Delete button is created from the other form, then you can pass the list as a constructor parameter and keep it in a field in the form with the Delete button.